# Proof that group with a minimal generating set consisting of $n$ elements of order $2$ has order $2^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group that is generated by $n$ elements with $n\in \mathbb{N}$, where all $n$ elements have order $2$ and generate minimally. To prove that the order of $G$ is $2^n$ we must use induction. For $n=0$ the only element in the group is the identity element. So the order of $G$ is $1=2^0$. The statement holds for $n=0$. Now we presume that the statement holds for a $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$. We must prove that the statement holds for $n+1$ to finsh the proof. How do I continue?

Comment: I wrote and answer now. You can assume commuative or all elements in the group have order at  most 2. But you need one of the two assumptions.

Comment: @quid thanks very much, i just upvoted your answer

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad we figured it out in the end. :-)

Comment: I changed the title since the original title was highly misleading and obviously false.  Feel free to improve wording if you think it isn't clear enough.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21456/discussion-on-question-by-stan-allen-proof-that-group-with-a-minimal-generating).

Comment: Upvoting the answer to stop this question from getting bumped periodically. Anyway, I'm glad to see that the initial confusion about the exact version of the question was sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first give the argument assuming $G$ is commutative.

You have shown the statement for $n=0$ and assume it for $n$.

Now let $g_1, \dots , g_{n+1} \in G$ some $n+1$ elements that generated the group (that is not generated by $n$).

Consider the subgroup $H$ generated by $g_1, \dots ,g_n$. This is generated by $n$ elements (and cannot be generated by less, since otherwise you could als reduce the number of generators for $G$).

Thus you can apply the induction hypothesis to conclude $|H| = 2^{n}$.

Now, $H$ is a proper sugroup of $G$. Consider the quotient group $G/H$. 
Since $g_{n+1}$ has order two, it consists only of the classes $H$ and $g_{n+1}H$. [Note you use commutativity.]

So $|G/H|= 2$ and since $|G|= |H| \ |G/H|$, the claim follows.

---

As said I assumed $G$ commutative. But a group where each element has order (at most) two is always commutative as $(ab)^{-1}$ is on the one hand $ab$ and on the other hand $b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$.

So you can either assume $G$ commutative or all elements have order (at most) two. (But you need one of the two assumptions.)